# Cordova backbutton destroy the CordovaActivity after use own plugin

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, plugins

I develop a cordova plugin that can create a file container for pdf. My Plugin have the functions `enterFullscreen()` and `exitFUllscreen()`. If i switch to Fullscreen and want back to defaut file container i want use the backbutton for this, but if i press the backbutton the app close. In my logcat i get this message:

[image]

**Here is my plugin code: java**

```
/**
 * Enters the fullscreen mode of a Container.
 *
 * @param {Container} _container The Container which should enter the fullscreen mode.
 * @param {boolean} _enableFullscreen True for enabling fullscreen mode, false for disabling.
 */
private void setContainerFullscreen(final Container _container,final boolean _enableFullscreen)
{
    Log.d(LOGTAG,"FileViewer -> enterFullscreen of container with id: " + _container.id());

    this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            _container.enableFullscreen(_enableFullscreen);

            FrameLayout containerLayout = _container.containerFrameLayout();

            /* first we must call removeView() then addView(), because the updateView() function don't work with fullscreen mode.
            //todo I must check this later.
            call a exception.*/
            mainLayout.removeView(containerLayout);
            mainLayout.addView(containerLayout,containerLayout.getLayoutParams());
        }
    });
}
```

**here the container class**

```
/**
 * Enables fullscreen mode for this Container.
 *
 * @param {boolean} _enable True for enabling fullscreen mode, false for disabling.
 */
public void enableFullscreen(boolean _enable)
{
    this.isFullscreen = _enable;

    if (this.isFullscreen && this.isVisible)
    {   // Sets the size of the parentlayout to fullscreen.
        this.containerFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(mainLayout.getLayoutParams());
        this.enableToolbar(true);
    }
    else if (!this.isFullscreen && this.isVisible)
    {   // Sets the size back to the values before it went into fullscreen mode.
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(this.containerRect.right-this.containerRect.left,this.containerRect.bottom-this.containerRect.top);
        layoutParams.leftMargin = this.containerRect.left;
        layoutParams.topMargin = this.containerRect.top;
        layoutParams.gravity = 0;

        this.containerFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        this.enableToolbar(false);
    }
}
```

**Here is the javascript code:**

```
// backbutton support for android in fullscreen mode
document.addEventListener("backbutton", Ext.bind(function(_event){
    if (this.fullScreen)
    {
        //console.log("We are in fullscreen!");
        this.fileViewerPlugin.exitFullscreen();
        this.fullScreen=false;
        _event.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
},this), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the original behaviour of `back-button`. You should `override` this behaviour using for example [this guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html).

Comment: i do this in my javascript